# if in mysql insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I would like to do this kind of thing:

```
 IF ((19, 13) NOT IN (select idUtente, IdLezione from partecipa)) THEN
 insert into partecipa 
 (IdUtente, IdLezione, 
 IdAbbonamento, 
 utente,
  prova, riserva) 
 values( 
 19, 13, 
 (select idAbbonamento from abbonamento where attivo=1 and idUtente=19), 
 (select concat(u.nome," ",u.cognome) from abbonamento as a, utente as u where      a.attivo=1 and a.idUtente=u.idUtente and u.idUtente=19),
  0, 0)
 end if;
```

but there is an error in the syntax

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF ((19, 13) NOT IN (select idUtente, IdLezione from partecipa)) THEN insert int' at line 1    0.000 sec
```

and on internet I can't find any solution. Someone can help me?

Comment: What was the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO partecipa (IdUtente, 
                       IdLezione, 
                       IdAbbonamento, 
                       utente,  
                       prova, 
                       riserva)
SELECT 
  19, 
  13, 
  ab.idAbbonamento,  
  concat(u.nome, ' ', u.cognome), 
  0, 
  0
FROM abbonamento       AS ab 
INNER JOIN abbonamento AS a  ON ab.attivo   = a.attivo 
                            AND ab.idUtente = a.idUtente
INNER JOIN utente      AS u  ON a.idUtente  = u.idUtente 
WHERE a.attivo   = 1
  AND u.idUtente = 19
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM partecipa 
                 WHERE idUtente  = 19 
                   AND IdLezione = 13);
```

Comment: Another question please...
if I need to do this kind of thing without selecting values from other tables, I need to insert specific values if that values doesn't exists.

Comment: @user1856906 Yes, in this case you have to insert these value directly.