# sql if in insert statement without select

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

yesterday I asked this question: [if in mysql insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960022/if-in-mysql-insert-statement) and the answer works very well.
The problem is that I need to insert a row in my table if a value doesn't exist. 
f.e.

```
 If('x' NOT EXIXTS in (select campoX from table) then
 insert into table (...) values (...) etc.
```

How can I do? on the internet I can't find an answer :(

Comment: what if the value already exist? what column do you want the value to be unique?

Comment: I think you require PL/SQL for such task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your table is named tbl.

```
INSERT INTO tbl (campoX ) 
    SELECT 'X' FROM DUAL 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS( 
                      SELECT campoX from tbl 
                      WHERE campoX ='X'
                     );
```

`DUAL` is purely for the convenience of people who require that all SELECT statements should have FROM and possibly other clauses. MySQL may ignore the clauses. MySQL does not require FROM DUAL if no tables are referenced.

As some other mentioned, you could use `INSERT IGNORE` statement here IF your  campoX is an unigue Or primary key field.

Comment: no because I want to insert a new line if and only if does not already exist a row with the specific value

Comment: Do you have two or one tables? You want to insert in table A only if there is no record X?

Comment: only one table. I do an example: IF('Max' NOT IN (select name from user where age=24) THEN insert into user (name, age) values ('max',24)

Answer (score 1):

Use dual table:

```
INSERT INTO campoX (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT value1, value2, value3
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM campoX 
                 WHERE col1=value1);
```

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
CASE 
    WHEN 'X' NOT EXIST IN (SELECT campoX FROM yourTable) THEN 
    INSERT INTO yourTable (...) VALUES (...) 
END CASE
```

Answer (score 0):

Inventing your programming language is not the most appropriate way to describe your problem.

Do you mean that you only want to add a row where that data does not alreay exist in the database? If so then make sure you've got a primary or unique key defined on the table and do the INSERT anyway - but disregard a duplicate key error. Indeed, with MySQL you can suppress the error generation completely for duplicate keys by using 'INSERT IGNORE....'

Comment: the problem is that I don't want to do a control on a primary key but on an attribute that can be also null.